# If I receive a pay cut, will I lose my Blue Card immediatelly?

Tags: germany, blue-card

I'm a Brazilian computer scientist. I have had a Blue Card since August. My probation period with the company I'm working for ends on the 23rd, and suddenly they want to reduce my pay by 55% (which would put me out of the Blue Card salary minimum). I'm already looking for a new job, but if I do accept this, will I immediately lose the blue card, or do I still have 90 days to find another job?

Comment: Let's focus on the "pay cut" question.  The other questions are may be best asked separately.

Comment: I'm thinking about if I should accept the pay cut so that I can have a salary while I look for a different blue-card job. Either way, I'm leaving the company.

Comment: You should separately look at the legality of such a drastic cut. You may be able to continue at your full salary while you look for a new job.

Comment: @user16259 they want me to sign a new contract on Monday cutting my salary. I don't think I have enough time to speak to a lawyer about this...

Comment: You have a contract already. Forcing you to sign a new one is illegal. Just refuse. And then speak with a lawyer.

Comment: @dda It may not be illegal to sign a new one if his or her old one runs out, but this is Germany so if it's with similar responsibilities it may be illegal yet. Indeed, ask a lawyer.

Comment: @gerrit indeed. But if the OP is still under probation until the 23rd, that's a sign that the OP is still on a current contract. And I get the feeling that the employer is pressuring the OP because he's still a probie. Sign the new contract or we prob' you out.

Comment: I think so too. It's a consulting company, and in the beginning of the month some prominent consultants left to create their own company and took major clients with them. I think they're trying to cut expenses and I'm just a convenient target because they lose nothing if I go

Comment: Well they could lose a lot if you sue them... I believe that, under the conditions described, you have a valid case. At least valid enough to warrant a sit-down with a lawyer.